# Iterate through <select> options

Tags: jquery

I have a `<select>` element in HTML. This element represents a drop down list. I'm trying to understand how to iterate through the options in the `<select>` element via JQuery.

How do I use JQuery to display the value and text of each option in a `<select>` element? I just want to display them in an `alert()` box.

Answer (score 414, accepted):

```
$("#selectId > option").each(function() {
    alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/each/
- http://jsfiddle.net/Rx3AP/

Comment: Its weird, this should work but for some reason it doesnt for me... :(

Comment: It should be $(this).val() instead of this.value like IT ppl said.

Comment: Only IT ppl's answer worked for me (and it wasn't just the "this")

Comment: It should be $(this).val() and $(this).text() for getting value and text respectively

Comment: @AmitKB - It's better to use the native DOM method to extract the text and values. 1) It's shorter 2) avoids constructing two new jQuery objects.

Comment: @karim79 First of all I was not sure if that was going to work or not but in my case it did not work. I have to recall the situation. Also thanks letting me know about "this". I would apologize if I found that working.

Comment: @karim79 I guess I was trying to call "this.text()" and "this.val()" which this wrong. I apologies for the vote down. Can you tell me how I can  undo my vote down?

Comment: I tried val() versus value and I'd have to test further to be sure, but if you have an empty <option></option> in your select list, val() returns an undefined error.

Comment: While this works, you don't know the length of the options within the loop. It be nice if the foreach had a property called length that you could use inside.

Comment: I had a problem because my control identifier had a point $("#selectId.id > option") so in this case didn't work, I supposed the point tell to jQuery selector that exist a class that is not found

Comment: @karim79 It's better to stick to one thing imo. combining some jQuery and some vanilla JS with each other like this is bound to having errors.

Answer (score 95):

This worked for me

```
$(function() {
    $("#select option").each(function(i){
        alert($(this).text() + " : " + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: If you stored `$(this)` in a variable it would be more efficient, i.e. `var $this = $(this); $this.text(); $this.val();...etc.`

Answer (score 33):

And the requisite, non-jquery way, for followers, since google seems to send everyone here:

```
  var select = document.getElementById("select_id");
  for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
    var option = select.options[i];
    // now have option.text, option.value
  }
```

Answer (score 32):

can also Use parameterized each with index and the element.

```
$('#selectIntegrationConf').find('option').each(function(index,element){
 console.log(index);
 console.log(element.value);
 console.log(element.text);
 });
```

// this will also work

```
$('#selectIntegrationConf option').each(function(index,element){
 console.log(index);
 console.log(element.value);
 console.log(element.text);
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want Jquery (and can use ES6)

```
for (const option of document.getElementById('mySelect')) {
  console.log(option);
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22413054)

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this too.

Your `HTML` Code

```
<select id="mySelectionBox">
    <option value="hello">Foo</option>
    <option value="hello1">Foo1</option>
    <option value="hello2">Foo2</option>
    <option value="hello3">Foo3</option>
</select>
```

You `JQuery` Code

```
$("#mySelectionBox option").each(function() {
    alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
});
```

OR

```
var select =  $('#mySelectionBox')[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
    var option = select.options[i];
    alert (option.text + ' ' + option.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$.each($("#MySelect option"), function(){
                    alert($(this).text() + " - " + $(this).val());                    
                });
```

Answer (score 5):

Another variation on the already proposed answers without jQuery.

```js
Object.values(document.getElementById('mySelect').options).forEach(option => alert(option))
```

Comment: This was soo, cruel :) I am at 10th alert of my 200 long list of options ;)

Answer (score 0):

After try several code, and still not working, I go to official documentation of select2.js.
here the link:
https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

from that the way to clear selection select2 js is:

```
$('#mySelect2').val(null).trigger('change');
```