# Jquery loop options in HTML format e.g

Tags: html, jquery, loops

there are many examples out there of how to loop through Select Options, e.g.

[Iterate through <select> options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950152/jquery-iterate-through-select-options)

but my problem is that I have to loop through an HTML string e.g. :

```
 var s = "<option value="0">OptA</option><option value="1">OptB</option><option value="2">OptC</option>"
```

How can I loop through each item please?
the idea is that I have a string obtained from a dropdownlist.innerHTML, and an ID to find between all the options in the innerHTML:

```
GetValueFromHTML(iValueToFind,strHTML){
  $(strHTML).each(function () {
    var iTempValue = 
    var OptionText = 
    if  (iTempValue == iValueToFind){
      alert(OptionText );
      }
     })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to give the result you want, you were very close. Just needed the `$(this).val()` really:

```
function GetValueFromHTML(valueToFind ,html){
    $(html).each(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if  (val == valueToFind){
            alert($(this).text());
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K2p9n/

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "<option value="0">OptA</option><option value="1">OptB</option><option value="2">OptC</option>";
var selectElement = document.createElement('select');
selectElement.innerHTML = s;
```

From here on, you can use the examples you have seen that allow you to loop through the options in a select list.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
function GetValueFromHTML(valueToFind ,html){
    alert ($('<select>' + html + '</select').find('[value=' + valueToFind + ']').text());
}
```