# Javascript loop through ALL HTML select <option>

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm surprised I can't find this code online!

How do I access ALL the selected indices of a select list? Not just the first one?

HTML:

`<select name="trends[]" multiple="multiple" id="trends" size="35"></select>`

js:

```
function moveSelectedTrends()
{
     var selectedTrends = document.getElementById('trends');

     for(var i=0; i < selectedTrends.length; i++)
     {
       alert(selectedTrends.options[selectedTrends.selectedIndex].value) //ONLY returns the first selected element!
     }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950152/iterate-through-select-options?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 16, accepted):

one simple way to avoid loops is to QSA:

```
[].forEach.call(  document.querySelectorAll('#trends :checked')  , function(elm){
    alert(elm.value);
})
```

the :checked selector is smart enough to work on < select > menus...

Answer (score 23):

Use `i` instead of `selectedTrends.selectedIndex` and test if it is `selected`.

```
   function moveSelectedTrends() {
     var trends = document.getElementById('trends'), trend, i;

     for(i = 0; i < trends.length; i++) {
       trend = trends[i];
       if (trend.selected) {
           alert(trend.value);
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for very large datasets.