# Use jQuery to filter a SELECT list

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to filter a SELECT list on the fly.

I have a list like this:

```
<div class="domainreginput" id="domainexisting_domain">
<select id="incartsld">
<option value="example.com">example.com</option>
<option value="example2.com">example2.com</option>
<option value="example.net">example.net</option>
<option value="example.rocks">example.rocks</option>
</select> <input type="submit" value="Click to Continue >>" />
</div>
```

The list could include domain names with any extension. But for this particular purpose I only want to show domains with certain TLDs. In this example, let's say .com and .net.

So if I provided a list of allowed TLDs, like this:

```
var allowedTLD = [".com", ".net"];
```

How can I use jQuery to remove any domains from the SELECT list that don't have a TLD that matches one in the allowed array?

I'm fairly new to jQuery and have tried searching around for an answer to this, but couldn't find anything quite like this.

If it helps any, this is the actual regex used to match allowed domains:

```
/\.(com|net|org|biz|info|name|tv|cc|me|pro|mobi|cm|co|ws)$/i
```

Comment: Take a look at this how to iterate through all options inside `#incartsld` select: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950152/iterate-through-select-options. Then check each value with your regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```js
var allowedTLD = [".com", ".net"];
$('#incartsld option').filter(function () {
    return !($.inArray('.'+$(this).val().split('.').pop(), allowedTLD) > -1)
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="domainreginput" id="domainexisting_domain">
    <select id="incartsld">
        <option value="example.com">example.com</option>
        <option value="example2.com">example2.com</option>
        <option value="example.net">example.net</option>
        <option value="example.bix">example.biz</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Click to Continue >>" />
</div>
```

Or alternatively:

```js
var allowedTLD = /\.(com|net|org|biz|info|name|tv|cc|me|pro|mobi|cm|co|ws)$/i;
$('#incartsld option').filter(function() {
  return ($(this).val().match(allowedTLD) == null)
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="domainreginput" id="domainexisting_domain">
  <select id="incartsld">
    <option value="example.com">example.com</option>
    <option value="example2.com">example2.com</option>
    <option value="example.net">example.net</option>
    <option value="example.bix">example.biz</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Click to Continue >>" />
</div>
```

Comment: This almost works. However, if the filter results in ALL of the options being excluded, it still shows one of them in the list. So a single domain will still be listed, even if it should have been removed leaving no options to choose from.

Comment: That was due to me using `.hide()` instead of `.remove()`. See the updates please.

Comment: Ok, that works perfectly. How hard would it be to then add an option if the above filter results in no options being left? So adding <option>Sorry, none of your domains are eligible!</option>

Comment: You could just add a check after the above code: `if($('#incartsld option').length===0) $('#incartsld').append('<option>Sorry, none of your domains are eligible!</option>')`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nfc2nxfj/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each($('#incartsld > option'), function(index,o)
{
    if(!$(o).val().match(/\.(com|net|org|biz|info|name|tv|cc|me|pro|mobi|cm|co|ws)$/i))
    {
        $(o).remove();
    }
});
```

I'm not experienced with regex so you may have to alter the `if` statement slightly.