# To get the first 2 html values of a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way I can select only the top 2 select value options instead of all 4 like how it is happening in the below example? I need

```
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
```

on button click.

```js
 $("#btnTest").click(function(){
     var options = $("#test").html();
     console.log(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="test">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button id="btnTest" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: maybe this will help you [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950152/iterate-through-select-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector to grab only the first two elements, and chain a `.toArray()` to turn it into an array of HTML.

```
var $options = $("#test option:lt(2)").toArray();
```

```js
 $("#btnTest").click(function(){
   var options = $("#test option:lt(2)").toArray();
   console.log(options);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="test">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button id="btnTest" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Or, as a string...

```
var options = $("#test option:lt(2)")
  .toArray()
  .map(function(e){return e.outerHTML})
  .join("\n");
```

```js
$("#btnTest").click(function(){
  var options = $("#test option:lt(2)")
    .toArray()
    .map(function(e){return e.outerHTML}) //get outerHTML of each element
    .join("\n");                          //join them with a line-break
  console.log(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="test">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button id="btnTest" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options) property for this

```
 $("#btnTest").click(function(){
     var options = Array.from($("#test")[0].options).slice(0, 2);
   console.log(options)
});
```

```js
$("#btnTest").click(function() {
  var options = Array.from($("#test")[0].options).slice(0, 2);
  console.log(options)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="test">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button id="btnTest" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```